# isset($_POST['submit']) does not work on form submit

Tags: php, email

My code is more less this:

```
<body>
    <!-- Signup Form -->
        <form id="signup-form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="submit">
        </form>


    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

<?php 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('php loads');</script>";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('enter if');</script>";
$to = "test@test.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$subject = "Form submission";
$message = "Test";
$headers = "test@test.com";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to     another page.
}
?>
```

I have the JS alerts as a sign that everything goes as expected. The first alert appears on page load so it is not a PHP problem. However when I submit the form, neither the second alert appears nor the email gets sent.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When I test your code, it works fine. Try `var_dump($_POST)` to check what's inside your $_POST-Array.

Comment: @abi I am not sure how to implement this. Any propositions?

Comment: Your code works fine (although I would place the PHP block at the top of the page)

Comment: Just put it in the line before your if-statement and I agree with MaggsWeb - you should move your PHP-Code to the top of the page.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, unless that file isn't parsing PHP.

Comment: *"My code is more less this:"* - what do you mean by that exactly? Are you using an JS/Ajax or bootstrap for this that you're not showing and could maybe even the problem here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- +1, I indeed had a problem with my js files!

Comment: @GeorgeVasilopoulos I had a feeling. My *Spidey sense* was tingling ;-) Glad to see this was resolved George, *cheers*

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the top of the page:

```
// Should show an empty array
var_dump($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    var_dump('Form was submitted');

    // Should show an array with your submitted values in
    var_dump($_POST);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: @JohnConde agreed. I was answering the OP comment about how to implement the `var_dump()`  and was waiting for some feedback to continue....

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is always set I think. you need to check if its empty. `if(!empty($_POST['submit'])`

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine after all. An external JS script that I did not include in the question was interfering somehow with the form.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

It seems that **your code is ok**
try it in another browser or so
it works for me as it is